# Talend runtime config file

Tags: config, esb, talend

I publish a RESTful webservice with Talend ESB and want to run it in the Talend runtime. 
As I want to use some variables from my own custom config file. I.e. database credentials etc.

This file should be external fro the OSGI deploy file to get modified after compilation.

Where could I place this file and how would I reference it in the Talend job design?

Comment: Isn't this [what contexts are all about](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforESBUserGuide60EN/3.4.1+How+to+define+context+variables+for+a+Job)? I don't know about OSGI so this is just an idea.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways we can load external config files to a talend job

1 . Using Implicit context option as shown below [image]

2. Using tFileInputProperties and tContextLoad

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Talend has a built in method (called implicit context) for importing your own configuration file and accessing those values in your code.  This works the same for both Talend ESB and Platform for Data Management and takes literally a couple of minutes at most to setup.

In your ESB studio go to file--> edit project properties. In the Project Setting window select Job Settings --> Implicit Context Load.   Choose the file option, set the path and choose a field separator.  The file layout is simple: key and value separated by the field separator you chose.

I use this for database credentials and other things as you mentioned.  In your job you need to add each key as a context and Talend will automatically load these for you at run time.  Makes no difference if its a Data Integration job or an ESB running on OSGI.  This uniformity across products is a great benefit of using Talend.